# How to identify customers who didn't make/used incoming call, outgoing call, and internet during the churn phase?

Tags: sklearn-pandas

I'm trying to solve a problem where data sets are below:

```
Cust_Id     period           Total_Incoming_Call   Total_outgoing_call  Net_uses

123        09/01/2018              0                       0               2

234        09/02/2018              0                       0               0

345        09/03/2018               1                      40               1

abc1       09/04/2018               0                       0               0
```

I'd like to get the output in below:

```
Cust_Id      Period         Total_Incoming_call   Total_outgoing_call   Net_uses

234          09/02/2018               0                      0                0

abc1         09/04/2018               0                      0                0
```

I know how to extract one column from pandas data frame but not sure how to extract multiple columns so I can tagged them as churn customers.

```
cust = pd.csv(....../.csv)

cust = cust[cust.net_uses == 0]

cust = cust[cust.Total_incoming_call ==0]
```

Should I used below or we have better method to do?

```
cust = cust[(cust.total_incoming_call==0)&(cust.net_uses ==0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

`cust = cust[(cust.total_incoming_call == 0) & (cust.net_uses == 0)]` works just fine.

You can also use .loc for the same purpose:

`cust = cust.loc[(cust.total_incoming_call == 0) & (cust.net_uses == 0), :]`

In case you just want to replace values for which the condition is False:

`cust = cust.where((cust.total_incoming_call == 0) & (cust.net_uses == 0))`

Comment: Appreciated for your inputs.